# Identifing error: 0x800442B6, occurs when attempting to use COM component

Tags: c#, .net, com, hresult

On one particular computer I get an error that I don't get on any other computer when I attempt to create an instance of a COM object using .NET.

I don't get the error when I use the same COM component through VBA in Excel on this computer.

I've searched for the error but have not found anything. I mean nothing, crickets, I'm in space screaming and no one can hear me...

I've written a couple of console applications that use different versions of the .NET framework and always get back the same error code.

Full error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800442B6): Creating an
>   instance of the COM component with CLSID
>   {2B763B2C-9F4C-4A65-8F47-338CB685D759} from the IClassFactory failed
>   due to the following error: 800442b6 Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x800442B6.    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)

Thanks!

Comment: It is a custom error code generated by that COM component.  It doesn't provide any error text with it.  So it is just blind guessing, you'll have to contact the owner or author for support.

Comment: I had suspected that may be the case and had contacted the vendor. They told me they are not producing the error, but I will recheck with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mr. Passant was correct. A bit of pushing on the vendor of the COM component resulted in obtaining the meaning of the error which helped me resolve the issue. Perhaps Mr. Passant would like to provide an answer that I could mark as correct to give him credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

- Add the code to log the time-stamp of the error.
- Then run [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx), run your application and study the log which surrounds that moment of time.
- Filter the Process Monitor's output the way you only see the API calls which have failed.

While it's unlikely that you'd literally see `800442B6` in the Process Monitor log, it still may give you an idea on which chain of the Win32 API calls has led to the error. Most likely, it will be a failed file I/O or Registry API. Compare the log to that of the machine where your app runs successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do not have access to the computer producing the error and the organization that owns the computer has very strict policies on what can be put on to the computer, but will keep this suggestion in mind if other options do not work.